# Image Processing - How to count objects on an image (stacked leathers)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to count leathers on a stacked leather image, any image processing help is appreciated.

After below some `python` codes, I realized my code is not a robust method, it can totally change depending on function parameters values and input images. I need a robust method to handle this problem. Thank you for your efforts.

```py
import cv2
path= r'image.bmp'
im = cv2.imread(path)
im = cv2.resize(im, (640,480), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite('savedImage2.jpg', im) 
im = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (7,7), sigmaX=31) 
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
im = cv2.inRange(im, 50, 90)
cv2.imshow('image', im)
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: original image1-before]

(leather count=8 in image, truth value=8

[image: processed image1-after]

[image: original image2-before]

(leather count=8 in image, truth value=8)

[image: processed image2-after]

Comment: I recommend you take a histogram of the image; sum each column to obtain a 1d list.  The leather strips will be peaks (or troughs) in that 1d list.  This breaks if they are not vertical enough...  Blurring the image before filtering might help too (see the many randomly oriented small fibers that could be smoothed away)

Comment: You’ve re-posted a closed question without bothering to improve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876996/image-processing-how-to-count-objects-on-an-image-my-problem-is-about-stacked — what’s the point? It will just be closed again for the same reasons. Please read [ask], and think about how to ask your question in a way that it fits this website and it might attract answers.

Comment: @Adam "histogram" is the wrong word for the thing you describe. just call it a "sum".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple idea and certainly not suitable for all test_cases. Note that the more time you spend, the more images you review and the more you read the image processing tools; You will achieve better results and find better solutions. So this is not something that you can get the best possible answer in a few minutes. The next issue is environmental conditions. The less you change the environment, the less error you will have.

```py
import cv2
import sys
import math
import numpy as np

# Load image
org = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/1.jpg')
im = org.copy()
H, W = im.shape[:2]

# Make a clean binary image
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
im = cv2.medianBlur(im, 5)

# Slice top of the image
org = org[0:20, 0:W]
im = im[0:20, 0:W]
H, W = im.shape[:2]

# Clean lines like a barcode
im = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (1,31), 31)
im=cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.rectangle(im, (0, 0), (W, H), 255, 3)

# Find contours
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if w < W:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1)

# Count lines
lines = len(cnts)-1
num = math.ceil(lines/3)
print(num)

# Save and show output
im=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite(sys.path[0]+'/1_.jpg',np.vstack((org,im)))
```

Note that the edges of your two test_cases are different and appear to be of two different types. So it is normal that you can not handle all the different samples with a simple algorithm. Examine the ideas, change the parameters, add new ideas until you finally get the desired result.

Output image:

[image]

Output number is **8** for this testcase.

---

Finally, I think if you can put the pieces together cleanly (close the gap between them) and always shoot from a fixed angle with a fixed camera and the same amount of light, you might be able to achieve a better result.

Comment: Dear Shamshirsaz.Navid,

Thank you. You are great, i will improve it also with your great suggestions.